# SQL Order table by group_concatenated column with most results to null

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to order a table by a column (Tavling) where GROUP_CONCAT has been applied, however
I can't seem to order the list so that it goes top to bottom starting with the row that contains the most results from the GROUP_CONCAT function.

So in this case it should start with the row that contains 3 results from the GROUP_CONCAT function, then the rows that contains 2 results, then the 2 rows that contains one result and the at last the null value.

Desired result:

```
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+----------+
| Spelare           | Tavling                               | Kategori |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+----------+
| Stellan Bengtsson | EM i dubbel, EM i dubbel, EM i singel | herr     |
| Kjell Johansson   | EM i dubbel, EM i dubbel              | herr     |
| Michael Maze      | EM i singel                           | herr     |
| Marie Svensson    | EM i singel                           | dam      |
| Ping Pong         | NULL                                  | okand    |
+-------------------+---------------------------------------+----------+
```

The view:

```
CREATE VIEW v_report AS
SELECT
    s.namn AS "Spelare",
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.namn) AS "Tavling",
    s.kategori AS "Kategori"
FROM
    spelare as s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN medalj AS m ON s.id = m.spelare_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tavling AS t ON m.tavling_id = t.id
GROUP BY
    s.namn
ORDER BY 
    tavling DESC;
```

Current result:

```
MySQL [exam]> SELECT * FROM v_report;
+-------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Spelare           | Tavling                             | Kategori |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+
| Stellan Bengtsson | EM i singel,EM i dubbel,EM i dubbel | herr     |
| Michael Maze      | EM i singel                         | herr     |
| Marie Svensson    | EM i singel                         | dam      |
| Kjell Johansson   | EM i dubbel,EM i dubbel             | herr     |
| Ping Pong         | NULL                                | okand    |
+-------------------+-------------------------------------+----------+
5 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should order by the count here, which corresponds to the number of CSV terms:

```
SELECT
    s.namn AS "Spelare",
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.namn) AS "Tavling",
    s.kategori AS "Kategori"
FROM spelare as s
LEFT OUTER JOIN medalj AS m ON s.id = m.spelare_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tavling AS t ON m.tavling_id = t.id
GROUP BY
    s.namn,
    s.kategori
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(t.namn) DESC;
```

Note that your current query is technically invalid, because it aggregates by only the `namn` column, while also selecting the `kategori` column.  You should be using `GROUP BY` with both these columns.  For the case of two or more records which happen to have the same number of CSV terms, you could add another level to the `ORDER BY` clause to break the tie there.

Comment: @luxaeterna . . . This is actually not correct, because you are using a `left join` and there might be no matches.  That is why my answer counts the column used in the `group_concat()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
ORDER BY COUNT(t.namn) DESC
```

This counts the elements in each group and orders by that.